# Netflix Conductor - java.exe error=206 The filename or extension is too long

Tags: gradle, server, netflix, in-memory, netflix-conductor

In my windows 10 machine I am trying to run Netflix Conductor in memory server.
and on this command `gradle server` getting this error.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\NC\server"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
        ... 8 more


* Get*emphasized text* more help at https://help.gradle.org
```